# Converting int to string then back to int

Tags: string, python-3.x, integer, type-conversion

How do I call out a particular digit from a number. For example: bringing out 6 from 768, then using 6 to multiply 3. I've tried using the code below, but it does not work.

```
digits = []
digits = str(input("no:"))
print (int(digits[1] * 5))
```

If my input is 234 since the value in[1] is 3, how can I multiply the 3 by 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string (wether or not you explicitly convert it to `str()` again), so `digits[1]` is still a single character string.

You need to convert *that single digit* to an integer with `int()`, not the  result of the multiplication:

```
print (int(digits[1]) * 5)
```

All I did was move a `)` parenthesis there.

Your mistake was to multiply the single-character string; multiplying a string by `n` produces that string repeated `n` times.

Comment: Thanks. that helped.

Answer (score 0):

`digits[1] = '3'` so `digits[1] * 5 = '33333'`. You want `int(digits[1]) * 5`.